# amadeus api where to get a list of hotel chain codes

Tags: api, amadeus

In Amadeus API, in hotel search, in the result there is "chainCode", is there a list in csv of all chain codes ?

https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/hotel/api-doc/hotel-search/api-reference

I'm referring to "chainCode" in this result example

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "hotel-offers",
      "hotel": {
        "type": "hotel",
        "hotelId": "XKPARC12",
        "chainCode": "XK",
        "dupeId": "501132260",
        "name": "Holiday Inn Paris-notre Dame",
```

How to get the hotel chain name from "XK" in this example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry we totally missed this question. Since you cannot retrieve it via API, please take a look to the [data-collection repository](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/hotelchains.md), which contains a list of Hotel chain codes.